# What are supervaluations?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

What are supervaluations?

I'm interested in how you would define these things formally for *first-order free logic*.

In particular, I'm interested in whether the collections of extensions are a set or a proper class and whether my paraphrase below is a correct interpretation of what the SEP article is saying.

I'm also interested in whether it *really makes a difference* whether we have an explicit upper bound $L'$ on the vocabulary of well-formed formulas with terms that might not denote in $M$.

What follows is my interpretation of the material.

---

The [supervaluation semantics for free logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/#super) seems simple enough, but it doesn't explicitly talk about signatures or languages, so I'm not sure whether the extensions form a proper class or not. I'm also not sure why we're insisting that the extensions are dual-domain structures rather than ordinary first-order structures.

We have $M$, an ordinary first-order $L$-structure.

Reading between the lines, it seems like we have an additional language $L' \supset L$.

$\mathfrak{M}$, the set of extensions of $M$, is the set of all $L'$-structures whose $L$-reduct is $M$.

And then we can define a notion of *supertrue* and *superfalse*. Let $\varphi$ be an $L'$-sentence.

$$ \varphi \;\text{is supertrue in $M$} \;\;\textit{if and only if}\;\; \mathfrak{M} \models \varphi $$

Where $\mathfrak{M} \models \varphi$ holds if and only if $A \models \varphi$ for all $A$ in $\mathfrak{M}$.

It's also possible to do without $L'$ and say that $\mathfrak{M}$ is the proper class of all structures $A$ whose $L$-reduct is $M$.

Both of these definitions seem to have the technical advantage of being compatible with ordinary first-order model theory; we can introduce the new notion of *supertruth in a model* alongside truth in a model without disturbing anything.

My question is, which of these definitions, if either, correspond to the ordinary notion of a supervaluation?

**Also, I simplified what the extensions are. Instead of being dual-domain structures they are ordinary first-order structures. This probably has no implications on predicate symbols, but may affect function symbols.**